# querySelector for RSS feed links logging empty text

Tags: javascript, node.js, rss

I am fetching and parsing an RSS feed (https://www.mangaupdates.com/rss.php) with Node.js. Then, I'm trying to take the parsed RSS and gather all of the links inside the items.

```
const mangaUpdatesRSS = 'https://www.mangaupdates.com/rss.php';
const DOMParser = new JSDOM.JSDOM('').window.DOMParser;
fetch(mangaUpdatesRSS, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {'If-Modified-Since': new Date().toUTCString()}
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.status);
  res.text().then((htmlTxt) => {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlTxt, 'text/html');
    doc.querySelectorAll('item').forEach((item) => {
      var mangaLink = item.querySelector('link').textContent;
      console.log(mangaLink);
    })
  })
}).catch(() => console.error('Error in fetching the website'))
```

The output is just a few empty lines. If I selected titles or descriptions instead of links, the output would work as intended.

Comment: `(htmlTxt, 'text/html')` — I thought you said it was RSS?

Comment: @Quentin I was following this tutorial: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/rss-reader-in-javascript/ But yes! I fixed it, thank you.